# Training NNs on GPU with DL4J

Tags: java, gpu, dl4j, nd4j

Could I train my NNs on GPU with using DL4J and ND4J and system parameters?
Windows 7 64bit
Nvidia GeForce GT 420M (CUDA computing capability - 2.1)

Comment: Hi! Please check out [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The answer to your question however is [here](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/cuda/supported-gpus?field_gpu_type_value=All&page=5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Largely no. GPUs from 2016 at least are recommended. We also require compute level 3.